# What's the correct word to refer to domain-specific entities?

Tags: naming

I've been incorrectly referring to domain entities as DSL, and I want to know what's the correct word for it. Let me give you an example:

In the system I'm working on, we have entities similar to a message delivery system. We have `Envelopes` and we also have `Recipients`. I've been using the term "DSL" to refer to these, but I think that usage is incorrect:

> *Also, our domain specific language use words, like Envelope, that are not actually envelopes, but templates. This is confusing so we should rename it.*

I've read about it on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and on the [Martin Fowler site](https://martinfowler.com/books/dsl.html) and it looks like DSL is actually some sub-scripting language, specific to a system. Similar to how the game Ragnarok Online is written in C, but the NPC messages are written on some sort of specific scripting language that only exists for that project.

So what would be the correct term to refer not only to business entities, but to the operations and everything else, that is specific to this system's domain?

Comment: "Domain language"? "Domain terminology"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Domain Model](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html)

> An object model of the domain that incorporates both behavior and data.

**See Also**
[Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture: Domain Model](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html)
[Domain Model on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model)

Comment: I was, indeed, incorrectly using the term "DSL" then, wasn't I?

Comment: Yes.  A DSL is an embedded language that closely represents operations in the domain for which it is designed.  Linq is a DSL.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809574